# XSLT: Converting a node with a child who doesn't have a child into an attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document I need to generate to integrate with a 3rd party vendor. Their paradigm is that any string elements are set as attributes, while any complex objects are separate nodes with the same rule.

I'm trying to use XSLT to convert our serialized representation of this object into their document format based on their .dtd. Unfortunately, I can't decorate these particular elements with [XmlAttribute] because their value could be null (I'm using XSLT to remove these nodes before sending the request).

Basically, I'm trying to figure out in XSLT how to do the following: **"For each child of my element, if that child has no children, convert that element to a property on my element."**

I'm working with the following snippet I've found that appears to do what I need:

```
<!-- Match elements that are parents -->
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Only convert children if this element has no attributes -->
    <!-- of its own -->
    <xsl:when test="not(@*)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Convert children to attributes if the child has -->
        <!-- no children or attributes and has a unique name -->
        <!-- amoung its siblings -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(*) and not(@*) and
                            not(preceding-sibling::*[name( ) =
                                                     name(current( ))]) 
                            and 
                            not(following-sibling::*[name( ) = 
                                                     name(current( ))])">
              <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:attribute>  
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this errors with:

> Exception::System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Attribute and
>   namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text,
>   comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.

My XSLT skills are a bit weak. Any help would be appreciated!

For more info, say the doc looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <type>Foo</type>
    <includeHTML>Yes</includeHTML>
    <SubRoot>
        <SubSubRoot>
            <ID>2.4</ID>
        </SubSubRoot>
    </SubRoot>
</Root>
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
<Root type="foo" includeHTML="Yes">
    <SubRoot>
        <SubSubRoot ID="2.4" />
    </SubRoot>
</Root>
```

**EDIT EDIT: I'm using .NET 4.5.1, XSLT 1.0 only. Doh!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I'll give it a try.

This stylesheet assumes that elements containing only text nodes are subsumed as an attribute of the parent element - even if text nodes are children of an element, in a sense.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*|*[*]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)]">
               <xsl:for-each select="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)]">
                  <xsl:attribute name="{current()/local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
         </xsl:choose>                
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)]"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
   <car nr="1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <speed>210</speed>
   </car>
   <car nr="2">
      <color>red</color>
      <speed>100</speed>
   </car>
</root>
```

You get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <car nr="1" color="blue" speed="210"/>
   <car nr="2" color="red" speed="100"/>
</root>
```

**EDIT**: Applied to your updated input, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root type="Foo" includeHTML="Yes">
   <SubRoot>
      <SubSubRoot ID="2.4"/>
   </SubRoot>
</Root>
```

Comment: Hmm.. getting an error with the formatting on one of the pattern matches:

           Exception::System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Expected token '}', found '('.
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime.ThrowException(String text)
   at <xsl:template match="/*|*[*]">

Comment: Works fine with Saxon 9.5. as XSLT 2.0. What do you work with?

Comment: Heh, I'm on whatever's packaged with .NET 4.5.1 :P

Comment: As far as I know, this only supports XSLT 1.0. Can you find out whether this is the case?

Comment: That appears to be the case, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, XSLT 1.0 only. All of the 2.0 libraries I could find are ones I'd have to get approval to buy, heh.

Comment: I think `<xsl:attribute name="{current()/local-name()}">` needs to be replaced with `<xsl:attribute name="{local-name(current())}">` for it to work in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: You are the king of all things. That worked! Now I just need to figure out how to only do that transform for a certain node and below and eliminate null nodes before I make the transform.

Comment: Doh, I've run into a bug in the logic above. While it works fine for the children of the children (and below) it actually removes any actual data from the children of the direct child nodes.

Comment: For example, if SubRoot above has a child node that I wanted to make an attribute, it wipes the value of that attribute (while leaving the node alone).. and this happens *only* directly on the specific children of the node I'm operating on