# XSLT: Performing a complicated transform on certain nodes and their specific hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a transform I'm using to integrate with a 3rd party vendor to force our object serialization into their structure. I've got everything working, except my big transform below I want to just operate on two very specific nodes and the hierarchy below them. I'm having a tough time figuring it out.

Here's my current XSLT transform:

```
<xsl:template match="/*|*[*]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)] ">
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)]">
          <xsl:if test=". != ''" >
          <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(current())}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(./*) and not(./@*)]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to perform this operation on two very specific nodes and every node below those two. Everything I've tried has been in vain. Any thoughts?

More Info:

Example Doc:

```
    <Root>
        <type>Foo</type>
        <includeHTML>Yes</includeHTML>
        <SubRoot>
            <SubSubRoot>
                <ID>2.4</ID>
            </SubSubRoot>
        </SubRoot>
        <SubRoot2>
            <SubSubRoot>
                <ID>2.4</ID>
            </SubSubRoot>
        </SubRoot2>
    </Root>
```

Right now, this is what I'm getting:

```
    <Root type="Foo" includeHTML="Yes">
        <SubRoot>
            <SubSubRoot ID="2.4" />
        </SubRoot>
        <SubRoot2>
            <SubSubRoot ID="2.4" />
        </SubRoot2>
    </Root>
```

And, let's say I just wanted to do that transform on SubRoot and SubRoot2, I'd want a result like this:

```
    <Root>
        <type>Foo</type>
        <includeHTML>Yes</includeHTML>
        <SubRoot>
            <SubSubRoot ID="2.4" />
        </SubRoot>
        <SubRoot2>
            <SubSubRoot ID="2.4" />
        </SubRoot2>
    </Root>
```

Now Imagine something like that on a 250K XML Doc. I'm trying to do the transform above on only 2 very specific nodes (that end up being about 80% of the document) and everything below them.

Comment: Don't make it unnecessarily hard for people to figure out what you need. Link this to the last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336635/xslt-converting-a-node-with-a-child-who-doesnt-have-a-child-into-an-attribute and post a _complete_ stylesheet - e.g. the version attribute is crucial information.

Comment: Tell us what you're actually trying to do, and post an example of what the input will be and what you want to turn it into. You've got some rather odd idioms in this sample along with some logic that appears self-contridictory, and I strongly suspect that you're making the task more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: It's very possible.. I'll update the question above.

Matthias: Yeah, I should have. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you want to match on the name of the elements (i.e. SubRoot and SubSubRoot) or on the level of nesting? Do your SubRoot and SubSubRoot elements have any other child content that needs to be processed or preserved, or does it just contain child element that you want converted into attributes?

Comment: Two very specific element names. Both of these elements have a huge hierarchy under them, and that's where I want the transform to run.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Interesting question, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet below achieves the desired output for the sample XML provided. I kept it very generic. You could make some of the matches more specific to the element names.

It may need to be adjusted depending on what the deep nesting of your actual XML looks like and how you may want to handle that content(i.e. knowing when to convert into attributes or to just copy forward).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="attr"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/*/*[not(*) and not(@*)][.!='']" mode="attr">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="attr"/>

    <xsl:template match="*/*/*[not(*) and not(@*)][.!='']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This definitely works, but now I'm trying to specifically exclude some very specific nodes from using this flattening logic. However, when I try to specify a node to "overrule" the above templates, the XSLT seems to gloss over it:

`  <xsl:template match="Request/DataSource">
    <DataSource>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </DataSource>
  </xsl:template>
`
(not sure how to indent correctly in this response, sorry)

Comment: What are you trying to do differently with this template? It is equivalent to the identity template `<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` since you are matching on the `DataSource` element and then inside the template generating a `<DataSource>` element and then applying templates to it's attributes and child nodes...